# Flush 'new' tag?

Tags: support, tags

https://stackoverflow.com/q/7416506 from a one-rep user had the tag [new](/questions/tagged/new). How could this not be a useless meta-tag? Wouldn't c++-new or java-new or whatever be more useful?

Comment: It should be allowed on the condition that user has also tagged with [tag:delete], to avoid a tag memory leak.

Comment: A side effect of `[java-new]` is that it would be incorrectly applied to questions about Java 8; same deal with `[c++-new]` and C++11.

Answer (score 6):

I'm seeing nearly 600 uses of the [new](/questions/tagged/new) tag on Stack Overflow.  It's a keyword in a lot of languages, so I don't think it should be blocked.  It probably does need to be cleaned up so it has a consistent usage though.  Someone should also add a wiki summary for the tag.

Answer (score 1):

You were looking wrong

596 
questions tagged [new](/questions/tagged/new)

I don't think it should be blocked just because of one user abusing it. Just retag it and do not think about it

Comment: That's correct: If all the times a tag is misused, we delete that tag, then we would not have any tag at all.